# app engine read local file in go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Im using go and cloud endpoints and  i have a pem file that im using him in  order to create signed URL.
When im running my app locally  and im providing  a full path to the  **ioutil.ReadFile** method   its working well.

On the server i tried several option on server  like this  but i get file not found...

```
APPNAME/files/key.pem
```

1. What is the correct path to the file?
2. Should i use memcached instead of **ioutil.ReadFile** for reading
   the pem file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine applications run with CWD set to the root of the application (the directory containing app.yaml).  If your application has the directory structure

```
- APPNAME
 - files
  - key.pem
 - app.yaml
```

then use the path `files/key.pem` to open the file.

If the .pem file is part of your application's static data, then it's best to read the data from the file system.